# Ho to change the main theme color of VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have set color theme I like but what I don't like is the below "cyan" color being used in the texts. Please check the screenshot attached.

[Screnshot from vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XV1e.png)

Comment: Go to extensions -> search for 'theme' and download it

Comment: search for `theme customization`, you can change any of the colors used in your `settings.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change `VS` theme press `ctrl + ,` it will open up the settings search for `theme`
and select you're fav theme

> OR install new theme from `extensions`  `ctrl + shift + X`

[image]

Comment: Hi @Zain, Thanks for your answer. The problem is, I like this theme. I just want to change that cyan color to something else. Do we have any particular property we could change in settings.json?

Comment: if you find this helpful please accept my answer!

Comment: @Shaktimaan want actually you want to archive can you explain please ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Setting.JSON` and create your own theme

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "activityBar.activeBackground": "#1f6fd0",
    "activityBar.background": "#1f6fd0",
    "activityBar.foreground": "#e7e7e7",
    "activityBar.inactiveForeground": "#e7e7e799",
    "activityBarBadge.background": "#ee90bb",
    "activityBarBadge.foreground": "#15202b",
    "commandCenter.border": "#e7e7e799",
    "sash.hoverBorder": "#1f6fd0",
    "statusBar.background": "#1857a4",
    "statusBar.foreground": "#e7e7e7",
    "statusBarItem.hoverBackground": "#1f6fd0",
    "statusBarItem.remoteBackground": "#1857a4",
    "statusBarItem.remoteForeground": "#e7e7e7",
    "titleBar.activeBackground": "#1857a4",
    "titleBar.activeForeground": "#e7e7e7",
    "titleBar.inactiveBackground": "#1857a499",
    "titleBar.inactiveForeground": "#e7e7e799"
},
```

> paster this code in `setting.json` and change as you desired